# relative height on absolute child, with a relative parent

Tags: html, css, absolute, css-position

I am currently working on my first year assignment (exam assignment). I have a problem with an absolute positioned article, that is inside an relative positioned article. For this to work, it seems like it has to be absolute positioned, but then it won't automatically expand the height of itself, when the content get bigger. Can anyone help me getting a flexible height, without ruining the rest of the layout?

content is relative
content-1 etc is absolute.

[test page](http://thomasteilmann.dk/bhus/?pageID=About)

the html

```
 <div class="content">
        <div class="content-1">
            <article id="info_about"></article>
            <article id="google_map"></article>
            <article id="misc_info" class="clearfix"></article>
        </div>
        <div class="content-2">

        </div>
        <div class="content-3">

        </div>
        <div class="content-4">

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs input#tab-2{
    left: 120px;
}
.tabs input#tab-3{
    left: 240px;
}
.tabs input#tab-4{
    left: 360px;
}

.tabs label {
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.8);
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

    text-align: center;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

    /* CSS3 TRANSITION */
    -webkit-transition-property: background;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-property: background;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-property: background;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.tabs label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
}

.tabs input:hover + label {
    background: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8);
}

.tabs label:first-of-type {
    z-index: 4;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.tab-label-2 {
    z-index: 3;
}

.tab-label-3 {
    z-index: 2;
}

.tab-label-4 {
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabs input:checked + label {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 6;
}

.clear-shadow {
    clear: both;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 5;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.content div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .content .content-2,
.tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .content .content-3,
.tabs input.tab-selector-4:checked ~ .content .content-4 {
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
    transition: opacity ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}
.content div h2,
.content div h3{
    color: #398080;
}
.content div p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    border-left: 8px solid rgba(63,148,148, 0.1);
}


/* CONTENT PAGES*/

/* om os */

article#info_about{
    width: 530px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 480px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}

article#google_map{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
}

article#misc_info{
    width: 350px;
    height: 110px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: man i can't, sorry! :/ anything replaced cause html to get wierd

Comment: The content div cannot expand because your `<div id="wrapper"></div>` element has the `overflow-y` property set to `hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using radio buttons for a navigation. I would suggest starting over and using something like this with a simple jQuery tabs solution, http://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabs/ but I was able to get your divs to grow with the content with the following changes:

**HTML**
Add a class of clearfix to the content-1 through content-4.

Example: `<div class="content-1 clearfix">`

**CSS**

```
.content div {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
    transition: opacity linear 0.1s;
}

.content-2, .content-3, .content-4{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}


article#info_about {
width: 530px;
min-height:480px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
margin-right: 20px;
float: left;
}
```